# Send Character Input to Sony Bravia TV via API

Tags: sony, television

Trying to develop a custom remote controller app with Swift for my Sony Bravia. One of the functionalities I want to have is a keyboard on the app, rather than having to manually maneuver around the on-screen keyboard with the up, down, left, and right arrows. I've been referencing this API: 
https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/integrate/ircc-ip/ircc-codes/index.html

I don't think it's possible to send letter input to the TV, so I've resorted to mapping text input from my application to coordinate jumps, and then send movement directions to the TV (starting from the letter q). For example, if I type "was", the application will send:

```
Right
Enter (w)
Down
Left
Enter (a)
Right
Enter (s)
```

This works, but it feels hacky. 
Does anyone know if it's possible to send characters via the Sony Bravia API?